# SocketChannel in Java sends data, but it doesn't get to destination application

Tags: java, sockets, nio

I'm suffering a lot to create a simple ChatServer in Java, using the NIO libraries. Wonder if someone could help me.
I am doing that by using SocketChannel and Selector to handle multiple clients in a single thread. The problem is: I am able to accept new connections and get it's data, but when I try to send data back, the SocketChannel simply doesn't work. In the method write(), it returns a integer that is the same size of the data i'm passing to it, but the client never receives that data. Strangely, when I close the server application, the client receives the data. It's like the socketchannel maintains a buffer, and it only get flushed when I close the application.

Here are some more details, to give you more information to help. I'm handling the events in this piece of code:

```
private void run() throws IOException {

    ServerSocketChannel ssc = ServerSocketChannel.open();

    // Set it to non-blocking, so we can use select
    ssc.configureBlocking( false );

    // Get the Socket connected to this channel, and bind it
    // to the listening port
    this.serverSocket = ssc.socket();
    InetSocketAddress isa = new InetSocketAddress( this.port );
    serverSocket.bind( isa );

    // Create a new Selector for selecting
    this.masterSelector = Selector.open();

    // Register the ServerSocketChannel, so we can
    // listen for incoming connections
    ssc.register( masterSelector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT );

    while (true) {
        // See if we've had any activity -- either
        // an incoming connection, or incoming data on an
        // existing connection
        int num = masterSelector.select();

        // If we don't have any activity, loop around and wait
        // again
        if (num == 0) {
            continue;
        }

        // Get the keys corresponding to the activity
        // that has been detected, and process them
        // one by one
        Set keys = masterSelector.selectedKeys();
        Iterator it = keys.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            // Get a key representing one of bits of I/O
            // activity
            SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey)it.next();

            // What kind of activity is it?
            if ((key.readyOps() & SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT) ==
                SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT) {

                // Aceita a conexão
                Socket s = serverSocket.accept();

                System.out.println( "LOG: Conexao TCP aceita de " + s.getInetAddress() + ":" + s.getPort() );

                // Make sure to make it non-blocking, so we can
                // use a selector on it.
                SocketChannel sc = s.getChannel();
                sc.configureBlocking( false );

                // Registra a conexao no seletor, apenas para leitura
                sc.register( masterSelector, SelectionKey.OP_READ );

            } else if ( key.isReadable() ) {
                SocketChannel sc = null;

                // It's incoming data on a connection, so
                // process it
                sc = (SocketChannel)key.channel();

                // Verifica se a conexão corresponde a um cliente já existente

                if((clientsMap.getClient(key)) != null){
                    boolean closedConnection = !processIncomingClientData(key);
                    if(closedConnection){
                        int id = clientsMap.getClient(key);
                        closeClient(id);
                    }
                } else {
                    boolean clientAccepted = processIncomingDataFromNewClient(key);
                    if(!clientAccepted){
                        // Se o cliente não foi aceito, sua conexão é simplesmente fechada
                        sc.socket().close();
                        sc.close();
                        key.cancel();
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        // We remove the selected keys, because we've dealt
        // with them.
        keys.clear();
    }
}
```

This piece of code is simply handles new clients that wants to connect to the chat. So, a client makes a TCP connection to the server, and once it gets accepted, it sends data to the server following a simply text protocol, informing his id and asking to get registrated to the server. I handle this in the method  processIncomingDataFromNewClient(key). I'm also keeping a map of clients and its connections in a data structure similar to a hashtable. Iḿ doing that because I need to recover a client Id from a connection and a connection from a client Id. This is can be shown in: clientsMap.getClient(key). 
But the problem itself resides in the method processIncomingDataFromNewClient(key). There, I simply read the data that the client sent to me, validate it, and if it's ok, I send a message back to the client to tell that it is connected to the chat server.
Here is a similar piece of code:

```
private boolean processIncomingDataFromNewClient(SelectionKey key){
    SocketChannel sc = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
    String connectionOrigin = sc.socket().getInetAddress() + ":" + sc.socket().getPort();

    int id = 0; //id of the client

    buf.clear();
    int bytesRead = 0;
    try {
        bytesRead = sc.read(buf);
        if(bytesRead<=0){
            System.out.println("Conexão fechada pelo: " + connectionOrigin);
            return false;
        }
        System.out.println("LOG: " + bytesRead + " bytes lidos de " + connectionOrigin);

        String msg = new String(buf.array(),0,bytesRead);

        // Do validations with the client sent me here
        // gets the client id

            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("LOG: Oops. Cliente não conhece o protocolo. Fechando a conexão: " + connectionOrigin);
                System.out.println("LOG: Primeiros 10 caracteres enviados pelo cliente: " + msg); 
                return false;
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("LOG: Erro ao ler dados da conexao: " + connectionOrigin);
        System.out.println("LOG: "+ e.getLocalizedMessage());
        System.out.println("LOG: Fechando a conexão...");

        return false;
    }

    // If it gets to here, the protocol is ok and we can add the client
    boolean inserted = clientsMap.addClient(key, id);
    if(!inserted){
        System.out.println("LOG: Não foi possível adicionar o cliente. Ou ele já está conectado ou já têm clientes demais. Id: " + id);
        System.out.println("LOG: Fechando a conexão: " + connectionOrigin);
        return false;
    }
    System.out.println("LOG: Novo cliente conectado! Enviando mesnsagem de confirmação. Id: " + id + " Conexao: " + connectionOrigin);

    /* Here is the error */
    sendMessage(id, "Servidor pet: connection accepted");

    System.out.println("LOG: Novo cliente conectado! Id: " + id + " Conexao: " + connectionOrigin);
    return true;
}
```

And finally, the method sendMessage(SelectionKey key) looks like this:

```
private void sendMessage(int destId, String msg) {
    Charset charset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");
    CharBuffer charBuffer = CharBuffer.wrap(msg, 0, msg.length());
    ByteBuffer bf = charset.encode(charBuffer);

    //bf.flip();

    int bytesSent = 0;
    SelectionKey key = clientsMap.getClient(destId);

    SocketChannel sc = (SocketChannel) key.channel();

    try {
        /
        int total_bytes_sent = 0;
        while(total_bytes_sent < msg.length()){
            bytesSent = sc.write(bf);
            total_bytes_sent += bytesSent;

        }

        System.out.println("LOG: Bytes enviados para o cliente " + destId + ": "+ total_bytes_sent + " Tamanho da mensagem: " + msg.length());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("LOG: Erro ao mandar mensagem para: " + destId);
        System.out.println("LOG: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

So, what is happening is that the server, when send a message, prints something like this:

```
LOG: Bytes sent to the client: 28 Size of the message: 28
```

So, it tells that it sent the data, but the chat client keeps blocking, waiting in the recv() method. So, the data never gets to it. When I close the server application, though, all the data appears in the client. I wonder why.

It is important to say that the client is in C and the server JAVA, and I'm running both in the same machine, an Ubuntu Guest in virtualbox under windows. I also run both under windows host and under linuxes hosts, and keep getting the same strange problem.

I'm sorry for the great lenght of this question, but I already searched a lot of places for an answer, found a lot of tutorials and questions, including here at StackOverflow, but coundn't find a reasonable explanation. I am really not liking this Java NIO, and i saw a lot of people complaining about it too. I am thinking that if I had done that in C it would have been a lot easier :-D

So, if someone could help me and even discuss this behavor, it would be great! :-)

Thanks everybody in advance,

Péterson

Comment: Thanks, but there's no such method that I know. I've looked the api for something similar but didn't find anything. In thesis, the write method should send the bytes right away.

Comment: @akarnokd That is correct. There is no stream buffering in NIO, and no `flush()` methods.

Comment: @Peterson Did you ever solve this? NB if `read()` returns -1 you should close the channel.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
System.out.println("LOG: " + bytesRead + " bytes lidos de " + connectionOrigin);
buf.flip();
String msg = new String(buf.array(),0,bytesRead);
```

Comment: I did, and it didn't work. Also, the buffer that it's used to send the message is different of the one used to receive something. But thanks for the reply.

Answer (score -1):

on the accept block, after the nonblocking, try to set the nodelay so the OS doesn't wait until it's own buffer is full to send the data

```
    socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
```

Comment: That's not what `tcpNoDelay` does, and it doesn't solve this problem.